# Can't update windows 10 after dual booting with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, updates, windows-10

I recently successfully dual-booted my laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. However, this week Windows decided it wanted to update. I clicked restart and update, selected windows boot manager from grub, and nothing.

It just started Windows without updating. Google doesn't reveal any solutions, is this a common problem?

Comment: Have you tried making Windows boot manager of a higher priority in your BIOS than Ubuntu?

Comment: Windows boot manager is the highest priority - Ubuntu doesn't actually appear on the list when I'm in UEFI settings